# Should be possible to purchase the upgrade using the same Google Play account (but different application credentials)?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

I have implemented in-App purchase to purchase a product,let us suppose i have added abc@gmail.com as my google play account.

I log into my app with one credentials,bought the product from google play and then logged out from the app.

Again i have signed into the app using different credentials but same google play account credentials, am not able to buy that product,it says you've already purchased this item!

is there any way i can make payment without changing google play account credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Any InApp Purchase made from an app is linked to the play store account or device primary email ID. It's no where linked to the account you are logged into your app.